# My merge is not correct in Oracle 11G

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, oracle11g, merge

Can somebody explain to me what I am doing wrong with this statement.  Its pretty basic....

```
merge into week1wrs 
using 
(select wr_id,fname,lname from wrname_id) on 
(week1wrs.fname=wrname_id.fname and week1wrs.lname=wrname_id.LNAME)
when matched then update set week1wrs.WR_ID=wrname_id.wr_id
when not matched update set week1wrs.Name_id='';
```

*** I am using oracle 11g

Comment: What is the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: You are doing an update in the `merge_insert_clause`, you can't do this `when not matched update`. Look here for some information http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use table alias names as Target (T) and Source (S)

```
merge into week1wrs T
using 
(select wr_id,fname,lname from wrname_id) S on 
(S.fname=T.fname and S.lname=T.LNAME)
when matched then update set T.WR_ID=S.wr_id
when not matched --need to be insert here.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
when not matched update set week1wrs.Name_id=''
```

**When not matched** you can only **INSERT**, you cannot update.

Merge syntax:

```
 MERGE INTO table
 USING table | subquery
 ON condition
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET col = expression | DEFAULT
 where_clause
 DELETE where_clause
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (col, col2)
 VALUES (expr1, expr2 | DEFAULT)
 where_clause
 WHERE condition;
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I said above